# is_double function in a while loop condition

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the fractional number count of a decimal number. I tried following simple code, but the loop runs forever.

```
    $var = 123.456;
    $fraction_count = 0;
    echo $var, "<br>";
    while (is_double($var)) {
        $var *= 10;
        $fraction_count++;
        echo $var, "<br>";
    }
```

I'm new to php so, forgive me if this is a stupid question!

Comment: whats your real intention anyway? you really wanted a loop in there?

Comment: **I assume** it is because is_double() checks the variable type, not the number format. Since $var is initialized as a double it will never become an int unless cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not trivial to deal with (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/language.types.float.php) for more information). But you don't even need to deal with the number as such.

If you treat it as a string, you can [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) on the `.` and use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) on the second part to get the `$fraction_count`:

```
$var = 123.456;
$parts = explode('.', $var);
$fraction_count = strlen($parts[1]);
```

Since PHP doesn't save trailing `0`s on numbers, this will work for `123.4560` as well, but be sure to input it as a number, `"123.4560"` will get you a wrong result.